# Limit 1 should be used with queryRow in Yii?

Tags: sql, yii

I am usually using `queryRow` to get a single record. eg:-

```
$lastReport =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
    'SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY created DESC'
)->queryRow();
```

I looked the MySQL log to know which query is used for it.

```
SELECT tbl_report.* FROM report ORDER BY created DESC
```

It seems that Yii is retrieving all the records from the table and return the first record.

So I think we should use `LIMIT 1` whenever we are using `queryRow`. eg:-

```
$lastReport =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
    'SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1'
)->queryRow();
```

Since the [queryRow](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryRow-detail) is returning "the first row (in terms of an array) of the query result", Yii should automatically add the limit. otherwise user will use this query to get a single record and that will cause to performance degradation.

Is my understanding is correct or I missed something?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using ActiveRecord for this? But from the class reference of Yii, you should get the first row with queryRow() indeed.

Comment: @davey working with array is easier than objects. But here I gave a simplified query for demo purpose.

Comment: It seems that it fetches all rows as there is no `WHERE`, so use `limit 1` to get latest report

Comment: I understand, i think LIMIT 1 is ok to use then, since it's unnecassary to get all the rows if you just want one.

Answer (score 1):

Yii should not add `limit 1` to query, because `queryRow` is designed to get results row by row, for example in while. Yii has limited functionality with raw SQL code, but Query Builder is available:

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('id, username, profile')
->from('tbl_user u')
->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
->queryRow();
```

More information available here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

You should rather use `ActiveRecordClassName::model()->findByPk($id);` or `ActiveRecordClassName::model()->find($criteria)`, because it uses `defaultScope()` and other improvements.